# Network activity indicator show in status bar on applicationdidenterinbackground

Tags: iphone, uiactivityindicatorview

Hi i am working with application download file from server. Every things work fine but the network activity indicator don't show me when i enter application in background.

The process is as below:

I am downloading files from server with ASIHTTPRequest. When my app start downloading file the network activity indicator shows. But after start downloading when i press home button and put the application in background then the network activity indicator hides. I need to show that network activity indicator till the app completed downloading file no matter in which mode app is. It can so me if application is in foreground or background.

Please help me to solve this issue. I don't know the process that i need to follow. Please provide proper process.

Comment: you find any solution for that???